# Why do I get The argument "env" is required, but no definition was found?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have the following directory/files structure:

```
.
├── main.tf
├── modules
│ └── Resource_group
│ ├── main.tf
│ └── vars.tf
```

Configuration files

./main.tf

```
module "app-rg" {
  source = "./modules/Resource_Group"
}
```

./modules/resource_group/main.tf

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "=2.11.0"
  features { }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "${lookup(var.resource_group, var.env)}"
  location = "${lookup(var.location, var.env)}"
}
```

./modules/resource_group/vars.tf

```
variable "env" {
  description = "env : dev or prod"
}

variable "resource_group" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
    dev = "rg-dev"
    prod = "rg-prod"
  }
}

variable "location" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
    dev = "westindia"
    prod = "westeurope"
  }
}
```

When I run a "terraform plan" I will get a below error.

> Error: Missing required argument
>
> on main.tf line 6, in module "app-rg":
>   6: module "app-rg" {
>
> The argument "env" is required, but no definition was found.

Why do I get The argument "env" is required, but no definition was found?

Comment: The error is telling you that your module has `env` as a required, non defaulted argument and you haven't provided it when calling the module (you only pass the source argument to link to the module and no other arguments).

Answer (score 19):

You have not provided the `env` input variable.

As there is no default value present, terraform doesn't know what env you want to use. You have a couple of options to fix that. First, you can include the variable value in the `main.tf` when calling a module. It would look like that:

```
module "app-rg" {
source = "./modules/Resource_Group"
env = "dev"
}
```

You can also include this input variable in a external variable definition file like `terraform.tfvars`, or pass it as an environmental variable, or set a default value in `/modules/resource_group/vars.tf`

Here are some resources on variables and modules by HasiCorp:

- https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/variables
- https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/modules/using-modules
- https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html#calling-a-child-module